# Integer solutions to $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2} = d^{2}+e^{2}+f^{2}$, where $a, b, c, d, e, f \neq 0$

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

How does one approach something like this? Is there an equivalent Legendre's three-square theorem for the sum of three squares in two different ways?

It seems like the only way to approach it would be via some computer power.

Comment: No, this is not the only way. There is a lot of literature on sums of squares. Some references are given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html), but there is also more specific literature.

Comment: Could you point me to some good papers?

Comment: Yes, I can. But before it is perhaps worth to point you to some questions at MSE covering this, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491911/two-sets-of-three-integers-whose-sum-of-squares-are-equal-and-sum-of-fourth-po), with an answer by Tito Piezas III, who has a website with such identities. Also [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A005875) is helpful.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786554/solving-rx-12sy-12tz-12-rx-22sy-22tz-22-completely-in-integers/1787274#1787274

Comment: This is not so. You can always ask in advance any number of times representations of a number as a sum of 3 squares. At least 2 times. At least 4. Any preassigned number.   https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1358472_representation_of_a_number_the_squares_in_different_ways

Answer (score 2):

There is a method to find the different primitive representations of an integer $n$ as the sum of three squares, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=19&ved=0ahUKEwi-lsi6zZjYAhWFKFAKHUM2C2A4ChAWCGkwCA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1007%2Fs11139-006-0240-6.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3zGqVLl98xLgVqGlDe_r_L). This gives solutions to the above equation. For example, we have $150$ different representations of $n=225=a^2+b^2+c^2$, and $96$ primitive ones among them. So we can choose each pair of these solutions to obtain
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2=n=d^2+e^2+f^2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Equation:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$$

You can write a simple solution:

$$a=q^2+s^2+k^2-p^2-t^2$$

$$b=q^2+s^2+k^2-p^2+t^2+2pt-2kt-2st-2qt$$

$$c=q^2+s^2+k^2+p^2-t^2+2tp-2kp-2sp-2qp$$

$$x=p^2+t^2+k^2-q^2-s^2-2kt-2pk+2sk+2qk$$

$$y=p^2+t^2-k^2-q^2+s^2-2ts-2ps+2ks+2qs$$

$$z=p^2+t^2-k^2+q^2-s^2-2tq-2pq+2kq+2sq$$

$p,t,k,q,s$ - any integer asked us.

Answer (score -1):

When $ a = -d, b=-e, c=-f $ then it satisfies the equality.

Consider

$$ (-99)^2+(-100)^2+(-101)^2 = (99)^2+(100)^2+(101)^2 $$

Similarly

$$ (-d)^2+(-e)^2+(-f)^2= d^2+e^2+f^2 $$

Where $ a≠b≠c≠d≠e≠f$

---

So infinite **integral** solutions are possible. (Not positive integral).